# Workaround for firefox bug that makes large images black when scrolling?

Tags: firefox

Bug is detailed here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=774617

In Firefox on OS X, putting a very large image into an "overflow: scroll" div makes the image turn completely black on scroll. The same bug happens on Windows but the image turns white instead of black.

Is there any workaround for this?